# convert decimal to binary nasm assembler 64 bit

Tags: assembly, binary, 64-bit, decimal, nasm

I need help to convert the decimal number fraction to binary. This is what I have so far but it gives segmentation fault whenever I try to run it. It works completely fine if it is changed to 32bit. 
Everything I know that should be in 64bit is in 64bit but I don't know if there are any other changes I need to make for it to work. Someone please help me

```
extern  printf

section .bss
   dsave:   resq    2
   bsave:   resq    1   


section .data                           ;data section

  fmt_float:    db  "%f",10,0           ; format of printf
  fmt_char: db  "%c",0                  ; no '\n' thus no 10
  fmt_dig:  db  "%1ld",0                ; print just one digit, e.g. 0 or 1
  fmt_end:  db  10, 0                   ; just end line

  dec1: db  '1','2','4','.','3','7','5',0
  bin1: dq  01010110110101B             ;10101101.11101


section .text                           ;code section

  global    main                        ;standard gcc entry point


main:
  ;decimal to binary conversion

   ;integer to binary

   push rbp                     ; set up stack
   mov  rbp,rsp
   push rbx
   push rdi

   mov  rax,0
   mov  al,[dec1]                   ; first digit
   sub  al,48                       ; digit to binary
   ;imul    rax,100                 ; 1*100
   mov  rdi,1
 l1:    
   mov  rbx,0
   mov  bl,[dec1+rdi]                   ; 2
   cmp  bl,'.'
   je   f1
   sub  bl,48
   imul rbx,10                      
   add  rax,rbx                 
   inc  rdi                     ; increment
   jmp  l1

f1:
   mov  [dsave],rax                 ; store 124

section .data
t:  dq 10

    global  l2

section .text
   mov  rcx,rdi
   add  rcx,3
   mov  rax,0
   mov  al,[dec1+rcx]
   sub  al,48
   shl  rax,16
   dec  rcx

l2: 
   mov  rdx,0
   idiv qword[t]
   mov  rbx,0
   mov  bl,[dec1+rcx]
   cmp  bl,'.'
   je   f2
   sub  bl,48
   shl  rbx,16
   add  rax,rbx
   loop l2

f2:
   mov  rdx, 0
   idiv qword [t]

   mov  [dsave+16], rax

   ;mov rdi, dec1
   ;mov rsi, [dsave]
   ;mov al, 0
   ;and rax, 1
   ;shr rcx, 16                     ; shift
   ;call    printf                      ; call c function to print

   ;mov rdi,fmt_end                 ; print end of line
   ;mov rax, 0                      ; no float
   ;call    printf

 ;print
       section .bss
   abits:  resb    17              

   section .data
   fmt:   db      "%s",0


 section .text

    mov rax, [dsave]  
    mov rcx, 8          
  l3:   
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdx, 0          
    shld    rdx, rax, 1       
    add rdx, 48          
    mov [abits+rcx-1], dl 
    ror rax, 1           
    loop    l3          

    mov byte [abits+7], '.' 
    mov byte [abits+8], 0   
    push    qword abits     
    push    qword fmt     
    call    printf
    add rsp, 8

    mov rax, [dsave+16]     
    mov rcx, 16       

 l4:    
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdx, 0          
    shld    rdx, rax, 1       
    add rdx, 48         
    mov [abits+rcx-1], dl
    ror rax, 1           
    loop    l4          

    mov byte [abits+3],10 
    mov byte [abits+4],0 
    push    qword abits    
    push    qword fmt      
    call    printf
    add rsp,8





   ; convert binary to decimal

 section    .data
  fmt_d db  "%d.", 0
  fmt_d2    db  "%d", 10, 0

 section    .text

     ; convert binary integer to decimal part

     mov    rax, 0      
     mov    rdx, 0      

     mov    rdx, [bin1]
     shld   ax, dx, 11                  ; shift binary value into rax
     mov    qword [bsave], rax 
     push   qword [bsave]
     push   qword fmt_d     
     call   printf
     add    rsp, 8

   ; convert binary fraction to decimal part

     mov    rbx, 0
     mov    rdx, [bin1]
     shl    rdx, 11
     shld   bx, dx, 5   

     mov    rdx, 0  
     mov    al, 1                       ; quotient
     shl    bx, 3   
     mov    ch, 0   

  loop1:    
     cmp    ch, 4   
     je loop2   
     mov    cl, 2   
     mov    bh, 0   
     imul   cl  
     shl    bx, 1   
     cmp    bh, 1   
     jne    loop1

     push   rcx 
     push   rax 
     mov    al, 1 
     pop    rcx 
     push   rcx 
     push   rdx 
     mov    rdx, 0  
 break1:
     idiv   cl

     pop    rdx 
     add    dx, ax
     pop    rax 
     pop    rcx 
     inc    ch
     jmp    loop1

  loop2:

     push   qword rdx 
     push   qword fmt_d2     
     call   printf
     add    rsp,8


  exit:
     pop    rdi                     ; restore
     pop    rbx
     mov    rsp,rbp        
     pop    rbp
     mov    rax,0                       ; no error
     ret                                    ; return
```

Comment: You should read about the [calling convention](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) if you want to call `printf`. TL;DR: put the format string into `rdi`, the integer to print into `rsi`, and zero `al`. However your code doesn't make any sense to me. For example you are overwriting `fmt_dig` and the _fraction to binary_ is squaring a number that isn't even a float.

Comment: Thanks. Even I don't understand the code but this is exactly what my teacher told me to do.

Comment: Maybe you took your teacher too literally because this truly doesn't make any sense. int->bin: and with 1, shift right, print in reverse order; frac->bin: and with max, shift result right, print, shift left. I wouldn't use FPU for this, instead load the number as int and only use the mantissa part (see IEEE754 spec).